# Remove last 2 digits from column1 and append those 2 digits to column2

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have 2 columns of string data type named column1 and column2. Both the columns contains data in the following way.

**

```
Column1             Column2  
ABCD12              5678ABC  
ABCD99              2341KFJ
GDHF33              1233DFG
```

**

now i want to remove last 2 digits from column 1 and append it to Column2. And my data has to be in this way.

**

```
Column1             Column2  
ABCD              12 5678ABC  
ABCD              99 2341KFJ
GDHF              33 1233DFG
```

**

how can this be done in SQL Server and SSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the last two digits are fixed, you can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions.

```
SELECT LEFT(Column1, LEN(Column1) - 2) Edited_Column1,
       RIGHT(Column1, 2) + ' ' + Column2 Edited_Column2
FROM   table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/308ee/5)

Comment: No last 2 digits are not fixed, it varies for very value

Comment: by term fixed, i mean, the last two values on the data are digits. right?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT(Column1, LEN(Column1) - 2) Column1,
       RIGHT(Column1, 2) + ' ' + Column2 Column2
FROM   table1
```